# How to use mysql database data into FusionCharts in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, fusioncharts

I want to Use the data which is store in MySQL database by running queries and show the data with the help of FusionCharts.

Now the fusionCharts uses json data format but MySQL data does not.

How can I display my database data with fusionCharts.I need help with the code.

This is my views.py (This is not all of the views.py just the relevent one.)

```
from .fusioncharts import FusionCharts
def chart(request):
    # Create an object for the column2d chart using the FusionCharts class constructor
  monthly = FusionCharts('column2d', 'ex1', '600', '400', 'chart-1', 'json', """{
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Monthly offense",
        "subcaption": "Month of July",
        "xaxisname": "Country",
        "yaxisname": "Offenses",
        "numbersuffix": "",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "label": "Jan",
          "value": "290"
        },
        {
          "label": "Feb",
          "value": "260"
        },
        {
          "label": "Mar",
          "value": "180"
        },
        {
          "label": "April",
          "value": "140"
        },
        {
          "label": "May",
          "value": "115"
        },
        {
          "label": "June",
          "value": "100"
        },
        {
          "label": "July",
          "value": "30"
        },
        {
          "label": "Aug",
          "value": "30"
        },
        {
          "label": "Sept",
          "value": "30"
        },
        {
          "label": "Oct",
          "value": "30"
        },
        {
          "label": "Nov",
          "value": "30"
        },
        {
          "label": "Dec",
          "value": "30"
        }
      ]
  }""")

  context = {
        'all_count': all_count,
        'total_high': total_high,
        'total_medium': total_medium,
        'total_low': total_low,
        'monthly': monthly.render(),
        'status': status.render(),
        'category_chart': category_chart.render(),
        'all_category': all_category.render()
  }

    # returning complete JavaScript and HTML code, which is used to generate chart in the browsers.
  return  render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'context': context})
```

So far I have tried this. I made a dictionary and then converted it to json and passed that to my chart object. it gives "invalid data" on the html template.

```
all_count = Offenses.objects.all().count()
    open_status = Offenses.objects.filter(status__iexact='OPEN').count()
    closed_status = Offenses.objects.filter(status__iexact='CLOSED').count()
    hidden_status = Offenses.objects.filter(status__iexact='HIDDEN').count()
    high1 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=7).count()
    high2 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=6).count()
    high3 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=8).count()
    high4 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=9).count()
    medium1 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=5).count()
    medium2 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=4).count()
    medium3 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=3).count()
    low1 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=1).count()
    low2 = Offenses.objects.filter(magnitude=2).count()
    total_high = high1+high2+high3+high4
    total_medium = medium1+medium2+medium3
    total_low = low1+low2

    status_data = {
        'open_status': open_status,
        'closed_status': closed_status,
        'hidden_status': hidden_status,
    }
    status_data_json = json.dumps(status_data)

    status = FusionCharts('doughnut2d', 'ex3', '600', '400', 'chart-2', 'status_data_json', """{
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Offense Status",
        "showpercentvalues": "1",
        "aligncaptionwithcanvas": "0",
        "captionpadding": "0",
        "decimals": "1",
        "plottooltext": "<b>$percentValue</b> of offenses are <b>$label</b>",
        "centerlabel": "# Users: $value",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "label": "Opened offense",
          "value": "open_status"
        },
        {
          "label": "Closed offense",
          "value": "5300"
        }
      ]
    }""")
```

Comment: Why dont you just convert the data coming from query into json format ?

Comment: now it prints put "invalid data" in place of the chart. I am updating my question you can see. @AlicanŞafakÖzdek

Answer (score 0):

In addition to directly specifying the chart data (or the URL for the file in which the chart data is stored) directly in the JSON/XML code, you can also fetch data for the chart from a database.

Django models map (roughly) to a database table -

```
from django.db import models

class Revenue(models.Model):
    MonthlyRevenue = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Month = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.MonthlyRevenue, self.Month)
```

Sample code -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Include the `fusioncharts.py` file that contains functions to embed the charts.
from fusioncharts import FusionCharts

from ..models import *

# The `chart` function is defined to generate Column 2D chart from database.
def chart(request):
    # Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, as dict, in the form of key-value pairs.
    dataSource = {}
    dataSource['chart'] = {
        "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
            "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
            "xAxisName": "Month",
            "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
            "numberPrefix": "$",
            "theme": "zune"
        }

    # The data for the chart should be in an array where each element of the array is a JSON object
    # having the `label` and `value` as key value pair.

    dataSource['data'] = []
    # Iterate through the data in `Revenue` model and insert in to the `dataSource['data']` list.
    for key in Revenue.objects.all():
      data = {}
      data['label'] = key.Month
      data['value'] = key.MonthlyRevenue
      dataSource['data'].append(data)

    # Create an object for the Column 2D chart using the FusionCharts class constructor
    column2D = FusionCharts("column2D", "ex1" , "600", "350", "chart-1", "json", dataSource)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'output': column2D.render()})
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/create-charts-in-django-using-database

Hope this would help you.